# Explanation about quicksort algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am following the lines of code for quicksort algorithm lesson, with these lines of codes:

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0] #Recursive case
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot] #Sub-array of all elements < pivot
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot] #sub array of all elements > pivot
        return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)

print(quicksort([1,15,7,3,9]))
```

I run the code successfully if the pivot is set on `array[0]`, but fails when I change to other number, say, 2,3. The error message is `list index out of range`.

Now I am confused how can it be out of range if there is 5 instances in the list? 
And why is the code not working if I change the pivot to other array positions instead of [0]? I thought that the pivot can be set to any other element position to speed up the process? Thanks!

Comment: It should be obvious that indexes 2 or 3 will be out of range when you pass a list of length 2 or 3.  Your if/return only checks for < 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will be called recursively, using smaller subsets of the array. The smaller subsets can have 2 elements, in which case, accessing to `array[2]` will lead to `index out of range`.

For example, in the above test, if you use `array[2]` as pivot, the code pivot by at `array[2]=7` and recursively call `quicksort([7,3])` and `quicksort([15,9])`. If you use `array[2]` as pivot for both of these subarray, definitely it will be out of range. (see the code and output below).

Apart from the `list index out of range` error. I would like to raise 2 comments on your implementation:

- If using pivot other than `array[0]`, make sure to adjust the set `array[1:]` accordingly (it should be `array[:p] + array[p+1:]`)
- One advantage of quicksort over other sorting algorithm (e.g. mergesort) is that it can be implemented in-place and require O(log N) extra memory. The use of `less` and `greater` kind of defeat this advantage.

Code example:

```
def quicksort(array):
    print(array)
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[2] #Recursive case
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot] #Sub-array of all elements < pivot
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot] #sub array of all elements > pivot
        return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)

print(quicksort([1,15,7,3,9]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 15, 7, 3, 9]
[7, 3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```